# How to get rid of a malware app "Chromes"?

Tags: malware

A few days ago I noticed a new app on my phone. It's called Chrome**s** and it has a logo really similar to Chrome's logo.

[image] [image]

It was detected as Malware by my antivirus at first, but after a few hours, I got a notification saying it's safe.

I can delete it, but it returns after a few hours. I tried resetting my phone, getting it back on factory settings, but it keeps returning.

What should I do?

Comment: Just flash stock firmware on phone. Do you have root? And what is your phone?